# Unable to change keyboard layout?

Tags: debian, kali-linux, keyboard, keyboard-layout

What the hell?

Installing a fresh Kali linux from an .iso file in VirtualBox.

I’ve tried everything, `localctl`, `dpkg-reconfigure`, `setxmap`, even trying to force write in `/etc/default/xorg.conf.d`, etc… Nothing works. I can’t get the keyboard layout that I want.

What’s weird is that:

```
$ cat /etc/default/keyboard 
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="fr"
XKBVARIANT="bepo_afnor"
XKBOPTIONS="compose:lwin,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

And that is the correct layout + variant that I want, but it doesn’t apply it.
I’m running:

```
$ uname -a 
Linux kali 6.6.9-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Kali 6.6.9-1kali1 (2024-01-08) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I’m on the latest release of VirtualBox (7.0.14).

Anyone had this issue before? Anyone knows what’s going on? Is it related to Virtualbox or the linux distro itself?